# How to check multiple parameters without a mess of 'if' statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm writing a program for myself that makes a meal plan. I want to make the meal plan customizable, so I have this method:

```
def getRestrictedMeals(meals):
    restrictions = []
    mealsR = []
```

In the method, I ask the user questions that customize the code and I save their answer in a list (The `getRestHelp` method just saves some answers as boolean.):

```
    print("Would you like only foods you aren't allergic to?")
    print("1. Yes")
    print("2. No")
    user = int(input("Please choose an option: "))
    print()
    restrictions.append(getRestHelp(user))

    print("Would you like only healthy foods?")
    print("1. Yes")
    print("2. No")
    user = int(input("Please choose an option: "))
    print()
    restrictions.append(getRestHelp(user))

    print("Would you like only Gluten Free foods?")
    print("1. Yes")
    print("2. No")
    user = int(input("Please choose an option: "))
    print()
    restrictions.append(getRestHelp(user))

    print("Would you like only Vegitarian foods?")
    print("1. Yes")
    print("2. No")
    user = int(input("Please choose an option: "))
    print()
    restrictions.append(getRestHelp(user))

    print("What is the longest cook time you want?")
    print("Please enter 1000 for any cook time.")
    user = int(input())
    restrictions.append(user)
```

Next I grab the information from each meal:

```
facts = []
for x in meals:
    facts.append(x.getAllergy())
    facts.append(x.getHealthy())
    facts.append(x.getGluten())
    facts.append(x.getVegitarian())
    facts.append(x.getCookTime())
```

This is where I'm stuck. I know I need to compare the lists the add the meal to `mealR` if it meets the restrictions, but I'm not sure how to do that without getting into a mess of 'if' statements. I can't make sure the lists match each other because if the user answers 'No' to a question, then any meal can be added.

If the user input is `Allergies` = No and `Healthy` = Yes, I want to avoid something like this (because I would have to go deeper and deeper for each parameter):

```
if(restrictions[0] == 0):
    if(restrictions[1] == 0):
        # I would continue going here for other parameters.
    else:
        if(x.getHealthy()):
            # I would continue going here for other parameters.
            mealsR[i] = x
            i+=1

    else:
       if(!x.getAllergy()):
           # I would continue going here for other parameters.
```

Comment: Most of the code you show wouldn't work anyway. For example, if `facts` is initialized to the empty list, `facts[0] = ...` raises an `IndexError` instead of adding a value to the list.

Comment: You need to use `append()` to add to a list, not index assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think the best approach would be to start with a list containing all of the meals. Then you start removing meals from the list according to each of the restrictions, no need for nested conditionals. It's a good application for [`filter`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp) too.

Comment: I agree, filter seems like the way to go. 

Just be careful with error handling when using this approach - if you catch an error halfway through the filter operation and `except: pass` it could cause somebody to get food that they are allergic to and die. Not particularly likely, but definitely something to think about while designing the system.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of questions for all the repetitive code:

```
choices = [
    "Would you like only foods you aren't allergic to?",
    "Would you like only healthy foods?",
    "Would you like only Gluten Free foods?",
    "Would you like only Vegitarian foods?"
]

restrictiosn = [None] * 5

for i, choice in enumerate(choices):
    user = int(input(f"""{choice}
1. Yes
2. No
Please choice an option: """))
    restrictions[i] = getRestHelp(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you just need to see if a meal is valid given a set of restrictions. You can do this using a bunch of logical operators:

```
def isMealValid(meal, restrictions):
    return (
        not (restrictions[0] and meal.getAllergy())
        and (not restrictions[1] or meal.getHealthy())
        and not (restrictions[2] and meal.getGluten())
        and (not restrictions[3] or meal.getVegitarian())
        and meal.getCookTime() <= restrictions[4]
    )
```

You may need to adjust depending on what the `meal` methods return. You can then use this function in a filter or list comprehension or whatever.